# MySQL: Mass Replace using a regex?

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

I'm trying to replace all instances of `&#160;` with a simple space  EXCEPT if it's surrounded by DIV tags. I've tried tinkering with the NOT REGEXP and NOT RLIKE within the replace query, like this:

```
UPDATE table SET column = replace(column,NOT REGEXP '>&#160;<',' ');
```

But it gives a syntax error. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about three separate updates...

1. `UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, '>&#160;<', '%%LOL$$');`
2. `UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, '&#160;', ' ');`
3. `UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, '%%LOL$$', '>&#160;<');`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, '&#160;', ' ') WHERE column NOT LIKE '%div>&#160;</%'
```

Comment: I tried this and it said over 8K rows affected, and when I went in and looked at one of them it all looked the same as before. *eek* lol